# Angular2 App img src broken by FAI

Tags: image, angular, src, 4g

I am facing a very strange issue with my angular2 app. 
Some users browsing the app with cellular-data can't access the css nor the images because the SRC properties are changed by the FAI in order to reduces its bandwith usage.(which is illegal by the way)

For instance the image's src : ./app/image/logo.png, 
[image: correct url]

Becomes : http://91.68.208.10/bmi/your-host/app/image/logo.png
Which does not works! 
[image: wrong url]

91.68.208.10 belongs to SFR a french FAI.

The point is the app works well over wifi/ethernet/other 4G networks. 
Their hack usually works well for other web sites otherwise we would have hear of it ages ago. So I think their should be an issue between this rewriting and the angular specific navigation / url pattern. 
Especialy because External ressources from other website (ASOS, Nike, etc) does not works either when called throught angular app.

Any idea how I could change or rewrite my url so the FAI hack will not break the webpage ?

Thank you

Comment: Update your tags, please.

Comment: what tag do you want me to use ?

Comment: Angular2. It is not AngularJS code here ;)

Comment: Haven you set the <base href="..."/> Tag?

Comment: @der_chirurg my href is : base href="/"

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGuillemet Thats ok I think